# Проблема со сборкой из исходников

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab

Необходимо установить данную утилиту
https://gitlab.com/jix/neca
Но встает проблема в том что нету ./configure а так же вообще ни какой информации по поводу установки делая все стандартные операции, после команды make получаю следующий результат[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Воспользовавшись информацией с данного ресурса:
http://mij.oltrelinux.com/devel/autoconf-automake/
получил config, но проблема не сдвинулась с места, так как по итогу запуска так же выдало ошибку

Makefile:356: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «install-recursive»
make: *** [install-recursive] Ошибка 1

Comment: Установите утилиту AUTO CONF

Comment: Спасибо, теперь еще нужно перечитать информации как с его помощью создать configure)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: 1. `/home/supreme/загрузки` — это плохая идея. в пути к каталогу, где осуществляется сборка, лучше не использовать символы, не входящие в ascii. при их наличии могут возникать совсем неочевидные ошибки. 2. также имеет смысл избегать сборки от пользователя с идентификатором 0 (обычно он называется `root`)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, а про рута можно подробнее? А то я для сборок запускаю чистую виртуалку и собираю под собсно ним.

Comment: @donRumata, первейшее и примитивнейшее соображение: безопасность. насколько мне известно, все опубликованные сборочные системы для запуска непосредственно команды сборки понижают привилегии (независимо от того, изолируют ли они перед этим процесс сборки). для полноценного обоснования такого решения, если есть желание, имеет смысл, например, порыться в списках рассылки мэйнтэйнеров дистрибутивов.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ну раз только безопасность, то наверное пофиг, потому что виртуалка потом обычно убивается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот проект собирается `cmake`'ом. Не нужно к нему прикручивать autotools (особенно если не умеешь). В самом простом случае:

```
mkdir -p build && cd build && cmake .. && make
```

За деталями лучше проследовать к документации и/или в гугл...

**Update**

Кроме того, в `CMakeLists.txt` ошибка при сборке с поддержкой OpenMP (автомагическаяя зависимость):

```
if(OpenMP_FOUND)
     target_compile_options(neca PRIVATE ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS})
     target_link_libraries(neca ${OpenMP_CXX_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

В `target_link_libraries` должно быть `OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS`, как и в предыдущей, а не `OpenMP_CXX_LIBRARIES`.

Comment: Все равно также выходит ошибка:
`CMakeFiles/neca.dir/build.make:96: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «neca»
make[2]: *** [neca] Ошибка 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «CMakeFiles/neca.dir/all»
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/neca.dir/all] Ошибка 2
Makefile:83: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «all»
make: *** [all] Ошибка 2`

Comment: @ДмитрийТолкачев, да, точно, там ошибочка в скрипте... дополнил...